# How to run jmeter script parallely on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I want to run jmeter script parallely through jenkins.
currently i have tried BZM-concurrency thread group and Parallel controller to achive this on my local machine, which is working fine. please help me to run it through jenkins, it get finish with success but script never starts. Do i need any plugins on jenkins to achieve this?
my set is shown below, let me know is there any other way to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the same plugins in Jenkins master (and all the slave if any) which are used in the test plan, the easiest is just to copy the existing JMeter installation folder to Jenkins instance(s)

Alternatively you can install the required plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

If your Jenkins doesn't have the GUI - it is possible to [install the plugins via the command-line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)

Comment: i cant see this plugins in jenkins, also they are already install at my jmeter thorugh plugin manager, please share exact step to configure my jenkins

Comment: I can see i have Ant plugin is already install, can i use it to achieve this in any way?